# exit with a return code from QML

Tags: qt, qml

QML language has a global object called [`Qt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#quit-method) which provides many useful enums and functions. Probably the most common used function of this object is [`quit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#quit-method). This function causes to emit [`QQmlEngine::quit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#quit) signal, usually connected to [`QCoreApplication::quit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) slot by the application developer.

But the problem is, this function calls [`QCoreApplication::exit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#exit) with return code 0.

My question is, is there a native way to tell the application to exit with a specified return code from QML? With "native", I mean a direct way instead of a work around or a hack(for ex., calling an invokable function).

Comment: Why do you consider a trick to attach an invokable function to a signal? It seems a quite clean solution indeed. I'm sure I've missed something.

Comment: well it is a solution but if there is `Qt.quit()` why would not be a `Qt.exit(1)`. So I just want to ask if there is a Qt's native way to do it.

Comment: Qt.exit(code) sounds sensible to me. You could try creating a suggestion at bugreports.qt.io.

Comment: @jpnurmi hello jpnurmi, ok I'will do that. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @jpnurmi hey jpnurmi, here is the link for the suggestion, https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-54360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the discussion in the comments for others who came here: This functionality has been added to Qt by the OP in [this](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/166873/) change to Qt. Having a look at the documentation of Qt 5.7 and Qt 5.8, one can see that this change was not in 5.7 but has made it into the 5.8 release [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qml-qtqml-qt.html#exit-method).